# JQuery remove/add ID class for an Infopath webpart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, sharepoint

I created two Infopath forms that publish to separate lists. I combined them into one form giving the user the look and feel that they are filling out one form.

Due to the form submitting to two separate SharePoint lists each form webpart will have separate submit buttons. The kicker is that the second webpart will only be visible once the user clicks the first button, which will submit the form and bring up the second webpart.

The webpart is hidden using the webpart ID('#FormWebPartID') and a simple CSS style of display: none.
On button click I would like to remove the class or toggle the class, which would ideally remove the display: none.

Below is the code for the first button which will display the second webpart.

```
<style type="text/css">
#FormWebPartID {
display: none
}
.newClass {
display: initial
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#show").click(function(){
$("#FormWebPartID").toggleClass("newClass");
                 or
$("#FormWebPartID").removeClass("#FormWebPartID");
   });
});
</script>

<button id="show" type="button" style="margin-left: 40%; margin-right: 40%">Add Action Items</button>
```

Of course I don't run it with both options in the code but I just wanted to show you guys/gals what i have tried. So with this code the first webpart is visible and so is the "Add Action Items" button. The second webpart is not visible but when I click the button which should show the second webpart, I get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are trying to remove the class "#FormWebPartID" which is the id of the element, not a class. I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Saxeen/qvX2v/) showing you a way to do this by adding a class I call 'hidden' and just removing it by pressing the button. It uses the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#FormWebPartID").removeClass("hidden");
   });
});
```

Alternatively, you can change the css properties of an element with the following jQuery:

```
$('#FormWebPartID').css('display', 'block')
```

Then you can just put the `display: none;` directly into the css of #FormWebPartID, with no extra class needed.
Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Saxeen/qvX2v/3/) for updated jsfiddle.

Comment: So would I add the class to the element? If so how would I go about doing that? Could I append the .hidden class to the #FormWebPartID element? I am trying to modify a sharepoint webpart and the element doesn't currently have a class assigned to it. It is wrapped within a <div> tag.

Comment: There is another element with the id of #WebPartWPQ3 that has a class="s4-wpcell" assigned to it. How would I assign the .hidden to it without getting rid of the .s4-wpcell?

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have misunderstood you slightly. I have updated my answer with a solution that doesn't require adding a new class, but instead modifies the css according to element ID. And regarding your other comment, elements can have several classes, just separate them with a space like so: `class='class1 class2'`

Comment: For some reason the 'display: block' is the only way that the webpart would render. Now I am having an issue with the comments field stretching the page to an infinite scroll. I will work on that later, i think it has something to do with the comments having the append feature enabled.


Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.